# Auto reboot if PC is on Idle for 30 minutes

Tags: windows, windows-10, script

I've created a .bat script, when PC is on Idle for 30 minutes to be rebooted automatically.
This is the script:

```
@echo off

rem Check the idle time
set idleTime=0
for /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %%i in ('query user %username%') do set idleTime=%%i

rem Convert the idle time from minutes to seconds
set /a idleTime=%idleTime%*60

rem Check if the idle time is greater than or equal to 1800 seconds (30 minutes)
if %idleTime% geq 1800 (
    rem Reboot the computer
    shutdown /r /t 0strong text
)
```

but this script isn't working. I've tried also to create a task on Scheduler when PC is on idle but PC is getting reboot every 5 minutes even if I am working.

Please can you help me with one script for that ?

Comment: I am curious, why do you want to reboot the computer every 30 minutes of idle?

Comment: I want to test first with 30 minutes, after I will increase to 1 hour, as I did on Task Scheduler but from Scheduler is getting reboot every 5 minutes.

Comment: This is just an observation, the fact the script is running in the foreground, prevents the user from being idle.

Comment: The Task Scheduler is the proper way to go - better fix your problem there, rather than invent your own.